# change menu position using css code

Tags: css, magento, menu

please check following url:

http://4.videomergerapp.com/customer/account/login/

and login with email id : kidsdial2@gmail.com , password : kidsdial2

than check this url

http://4.videomergerapp.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/editprofile/

you can see a) seller profile, new products...etc as a vertical menu.

i need to convert this horizonatl menu to vertical menu bar and move these menu items to bit top

i am using this css :

```
ul.wk_cont_ul li  {
 display: inline-block;

}
```

but its not working.

below you can see complete code of the file :

```
<?php echo  Mage::app()->getLayout()
->createBlock('core/template')
->setTemplate('marketplace/navigation.phtml')
->toHtml(); ?>


<?php echo  Mage::app()->getLayout()
->createBlock('core/template')
->setTemplate('mpassignproduct/navigation.phtml')
->toHtml(); ?>

<?php echo  Mage::app()->getLayout()
->createBlock('core/template')
->setTemplate('mpmassuploadaddons/accountnavigationlink.phtml')
->toHtml(); ?>

<?php echo  Mage::app()->getLayout()
->createBlock('core/template')
->setTemplate('mpshippingmanager/shippingleftlink.phtml')
->toHtml(); ?>

    <?php 
    $isPartner= Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->isPartner();
    $helper = Mage::helper('marketplace');
    if($isPartner==1){?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined'){
            document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
        }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { 
                new nicEditor({fullPanel : true}).panelInstance('compdesi');
                <?php
                if(Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_options/partner_policy_approval')){?>
                    new nicEditor({fullPanel : true}).panelInstance('returnpolicy');
                    new nicEditor({fullPanel : true}).panelInstance('shippingpolicy');
                <?php
                }?>
            });
        </script>
        <script src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/colorpicker/js/colorpicker.js'); ?>"></script>
        <?php $paymentDetail=Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getPaymentDetailById(); ?>

        <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/editProfile') ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form-profile-validate">
            <div class="page-title">
                <h1 style="float:left;"><?php echo $helper->__('Edit Profile Information') ?></h1>
                <button class="button wk_mp_btn" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Save Profile') ?>" type="submit" id="save_butn">
                    <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Save Profile') ?></span></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <?php $formKey = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo $formKey; ?>" />
            <div class="wk_mp_design">
                <div class="block block-account">   
                    <div class="block-title">   
                        <strong><span><h4><?php echo $helper->__('Profile Information') ?></h4></span></strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="fieldset wk_mp_fieldset">
                    <ul class="form-list">
                        <li class="fields">
                        <?php $partner=Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getPartnerProfileById(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId());
                            if($partner['wantpartner']==1){?> 
                                <div class="profile">
                                    <label for="twitterid"><?php echo $helper->__('Twitter ID') ?> </label>
                                    <?php
                                    if(Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_hint_status') && Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_tw')){?>
                                        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/quest.png'); ?>" class='questimg' title="<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_tw') ?>"/>
                                    <?php
                                    } ?>
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                         <input type="text" id="twitterid" name="twitterid" value="<?php echo $partner['twitterid']; ?>" title="twitterid" class="input-text" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="profile">
                                    <label for="facebookid"><?php echo $helper->__('Facebook ID') ?> </label>
                                    <?php
                                    if(Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_hint_status') && Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_fb')){?>
                                        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/quest.png'); ?>" class='questimg' title="<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_fb') ?>"/>
                                    <?php
                                    } ?>
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                         <input type="text" id="facebookid" name="facebookid" value="<?php echo $partner['facebookid']; ?>" title="facebookid" class="input-text" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="profile">
                                    <label for="twitterid"><?php echo $helper->__('Contact Number') ?> </label>
                                    <?php
                                    if(Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_hint_status') && Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_cn')){?>
                                        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/quest.png'); ?>" class='questimg' title="<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_cn') ?>"/>
                                    <?php
                                    } ?>
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                         <input type="text" id="contactnumber" name="contactnumber" value="<?php echo $partner['contactnumber']; ?>" title="twitterid" class="input-text" placeholder="<?php echo $helper->__('Enter Mobile Number with country code ex: +91 9999999999') ?>"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="profile">
                                    <label for="backgroundth"><?php echo $helper->__('Theme : Background Color') ?> </label>
                                    <?php
                                    if(Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_hint_status') && Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_bc')){?>
                                        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/quest.png'); ?>" class='questimg' title="<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_bc') ?>"/>
                                    <?php
                                    } ?>
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                         <input type="text" id="backgroundth" name="backgroundth" value="<?php echo $partner['backgroundth']; ?>" title="backgroundth" class="input-text" />
                                         <span class="color_pick" style="background-color:<?php echo $partner['backgroundth']; ?>"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="profile">
                                    <label for="shoptitle"><?php echo $helper->__('Shop Title') ?></label>
                                    <?php
                                    if(Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_hint_status') && Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_shop')){?>
                                        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/quest.png'); ?>" class='questimg' title="<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_shop') ?>"/>
                                    <?php
                                    } ?>
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                         <input type="text" id="shoptitle" name="shoptitle" value="<?php echo $partner['shoptitle']; ?>" title="shoptitle" class="input-text" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="profile">
                                    <label for="bannerpic"> <?php echo $helper->__('Company Banner') ?> </label>
                                    <?php
                                    if(Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_hint_status') && Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_banner')){?>
                                        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/quest.png'); ?>" class='questimg' title="<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_banner') ?>"/>
                                    <?php
                                    } ?>
                                    <label class="input-box-notification input-box-notification1">(<?php echo $helper->__("Upload 700px X 100px for better look"); ?>)</label>
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <input type="file" id="bannerpic" name="bannerpic"  title="bannerpic" class="input-text banner" size="26" />
                                        <div class="profileimage_set">
                                            <div class="setimage">
                                                <img class="wk_banner" alt=" <?php echo $helper->__('no image') ?>" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'avatar/'.$partner['bannerpic']; ?>"/>
                                                <?php
                                                $collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getCollection();
                                                $collection->addFieldToFilter('mageuserid',array('eq'=>Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId()));
                                                foreach($collection as  $value){ 
                                                    $bannerpic = $value->getBannerpic(); 
                                                    $logopic = $value->getLogopic(); 
                                                }
                                                if($bannerpic){
                                                ?>
                                                <span class="wk_profileimagedelete" title="Delete">
                                                    <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/deleteIcon.png'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $helper->__('Delete Image')?>" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Delete Image')?>"/>
                                                </span>
                                                <?php
                                                }?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="profile">
                                    <label for="logopic"> <?php echo $helper->__('Company Logo') ?> </label>
                                    <?php
                                    if(Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_hint_status') && Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_logo')){?>
                                        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/quest.png'); ?>" class='questimg' title="<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_logo') ?>"/>
                                    <?php
                                    } ?>
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <input type="file" id="logopic" alt="no image" name="logopic"  title="logopic" class="input-text banner" size="26"/>
                                        <div class="logoimage_set">
                                            <div class="setimage">
                                                <img class="prev_img" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'avatar/'.$partner['logopic']; ?>"/>
                                                <?php
                                                if($logopic){
                                                ?>
                                                <span class="wk_logoimagedelete" title="Delete">
                                                    <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/deleteIcon.png'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $helper->__('Delete Image')?>" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Delete Image')?>"/>
                                                </span>
                                                <?php
                                                }?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="profile">
                                    <label for="complocality"><?php echo $helper->__('Company Locality') ?></label>
                                    <?php
                                    if(Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_hint_status') && Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_loc')){?>
                                        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/quest.png'); ?>" class='questimg' title="<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_loc') ?>"/>
                                    <?php
                                    } ?>
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                         <input type="text" id="complocality" name="complocality" value="<?php echo $partner['complocality']; ?>" title="complocality" class="input-text" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="profile">
                                    <label for="compdesi"><?php echo $helper->__('Company Description') ?></label>
                                    <?php
                                    if(Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_hint_status') && Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_desciption')){?>
                                        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/quest.png'); ?>" class='questimg' title="<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_desciption') ?>"/>
                                    <?php
                                    } ?>
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                         <textarea type="text" id="compdesi" name="compdesi" title="compdesi" class="input-text compdesi" ><?php echo $partner['compdesi']; ?> </textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                if(Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_options/partner_policy_approval')){?>
                                    <div class="profile">
                                        <label><?php echo $helper->__('Return Policy') ?></label>
                                        <?php
                                        if(Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_hint_status') && Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/returnpolicy')){?>
                                            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/quest.png'); ?>" class='questimg' title="<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/returnpolicy') ?>"/>
                                        <?php
                                        } ?>
                                        <div class="input-box">
                                             <textarea type="text" id="returnpolicy" name="returnpolicy" title="returnpolicy" class="input-text compdesi" ><?php echo $partner['returnpolicy']; ?> </textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="profile">
                                        <label><?php echo $helper->__('Shipping Policy') ?></label>
                                        <?php
                                        if(Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_hint_status') && Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/shippingpolicy')){?>
                                            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/quest.png'); ?>" class='questimg' title="<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/shippingpolicy') ?>"/>
                                        <?php
                                        } ?>
                                        <div class="input-box">
                                             <textarea type="text" id="shippingpolicy" name="shippingpolicy" title="shippingpolicy" class="input-text compdesi" ><?php echo $partner['shippingpolicy']; ?> </textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <?php
                                } ?>
                                <div class="profile">
                                    <label for="countrypic"> <?php echo $helper->__('Country') ?> </label>
                                    <?php
                                    if(Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_hint_status') && Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_country')){?>
                                        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/quest.png'); ?>" class='questimg' title="<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_country') ?>"/>
                                    <?php
                                    } ?>
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                         <select name="countrypic" id="countrypic">
                                            <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled"><?php echo $helper->__('Select Country')?></option>
                                        <?php foreach(Mage::getModel('directory/country')->getResourceCollection()->loadByStore()->toOptionArray(true) as $country){?>
                                            <option <?php 
                                            if($country['value']!=''){
                                            echo ($partner['countrypic']==$country['value']?"selected='selected'":""); ?>value="<?php echo $country['value']; ?>"><?php echo $country['label'];?></option>
                                        <?php 
                                          }
                                        } ?>
                                        </select>
                                        <img class="country_img_prev" alt="no image" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/country/countryflags/').strtoupper($partner['countrypic']==""?"xx":$partner['countrypic']).".png"; ?>"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="profile">   
                                    <label for="meta_keywords"><?php echo $helper->__('Meta Keywords') ?></label>
                                    <label class="input-box-notification">(<?php echo $helper->__("Enter Meta Keywords Comma(',') Separated.."); ?>)</label>
                                    <?php
                                    if(Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_hint_status') && Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_meta')){?>
                                        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/quest.png'); ?>" class='questimg' title="<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_meta') ?>"/>
                                    <?php
                                    } ?>
                                    <div class="input-box">         
                                        <textarea type="text" id="meta_keywords" name="meta_keyword" title="Meta Keyword" class="input-text compdesi" ><?php echo $partner['meta_keyword']; ?> </textarea>
                                    </div>  
                                </div>  
                                <div class="profile">   
                                    <label for="meta_description"><?php echo $helper->__('Meta Description') ?></label> 
                                    <?php
                                    if(Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_hint_status') && Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_mdesc')){?>
                                        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/quest.png'); ?>" class='questimg' title="<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_mdesc') ?>"/>
                                    <?php
                                    } ?>
                                    <div class="input-box"> 
                                        <textarea type="text" id="meta_description" name="meta_description" title="Meta Description" class="input-text compdesi" ><?php echo $partner['meta_description']; ?> </textarea>   
                                    </div>  
                                </div>                          
                            <?php } ?>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <br/><br/>
        <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/payment') ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form-payment-validate">
            <div class="page-title">
                <h1 style="float:left;"><?php echo $helper->__('Edit Payment Information') ?></h1>
                <button class="button wk_mp_btn" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Save Payment') ?>" type="submit" id="savepaym">
                    <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Save Payment') ?></span></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <?php $formKey = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo $formKey; ?>" />
            <div class="wk_mp_design">
                <div class="block block-account">   
                    <div class="block-title">   
                        <strong><span><h4><?php echo $helper->__('Payment Information') ?></h4></span></strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="fieldset wk_mp_fieldset">
                    <ul class="form-list">
                        <li class="fields">
                            <div class="field">
                                <label><?php echo $helper->__('Payment Details') ?></label>
                                <?php
                                if(Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_hint_status') && Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_bank')){?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/quest.png'); ?>" class='questimg' title="<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/profile_bank') ?>"/>
                                <?php
                                } ?>
                                <div class="input-box">
                                    <textarea class="input-text" name="paymentsource" id="paymentsource" title="payment source" cols="1" rows="3" ><?php echo $paymentDetail; ?></textarea>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>      
            </div>      
        </form>
        <br/><br/>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml(); ?>

        <div class="grid_6 pull_18 col-left sidebar"> </div>
        <div class="profile">
            <div class="wk_profile_links">
                <a class="btn_primary" id="cprofile" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('marketplace/seller/profile').$partner['profileurl']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $helper->__('View Profile') ?></a>
            </div>
            <div class="wk_profile_links">
                <a class="btn_primary" id="ccollection" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('marketplace/seller/collection').$partner['profileurl']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $helper->__('View Collection') ?></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons-set">
            <p class="back-link">
                <a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript: window.history.back();" class="left">&laquo; <?php echo $helper->__('Back') ?></a>
            </p>
        </div>

        <script>
            $wk_jq=jQuery.noConflict();
            (function($wk_jq){
                $wk_jq(function(){
                    var dataForm = new VarienForm('form-profile-validate', true);
                    $wk_jq('.color_pick').ColorPicker({
                        color: '<?php echo $partner['backgroundth']; ?>',
                        onShow: function (colpkr) {
                            $wk_jq(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
                            return false;
                        },
                        onHide: function (colpkr) {
                            $wk_jq(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
                            return false;
                        },
                        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                            $wk_jq('#backgroundth').val('#' + hex);
                            $wk_jq('.color_pick').css('background-color','#'+hex);
                        }
                    }); 
                    $wk_jq('#countrypic').change(function(){
                        $wk_jq('#countrylist').val($wk_jq(this).val());
                        $wk_jq('.country_img_prev').attr('src','<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl("marketplace/images/country/countryflags/")?>'+$wk_jq(this).val()+'.png')
                        var address=$wk_jq(this).find('option[value="'+$wk_jq(this).val()+'"]').text();//address which you want Longitude and Latitude
                        $wk_jq.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json",
                            data: {'address': address,'sensor':false},
                            success: function(data){
                                if(data.results.length){
                                    $wk_jq('#country-latitude').val(data.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
                                    $wk_jq('#country-longitude').val(data.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
                                }else{
                                    $wk_jq('#country-latitude').val('invalid address');
                                    $wk_jq('#country-longitude').val('invalid address');
                               }
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    $wk_jq('#logopic,#bannerpic').change(function(){
                        var imagename=$wk_jq(this).val();
                        var image=imagename.split("."); 
                        image=image[1];
                        if(image!='jpg'){
                            if(image!='jpeg'){
                                if(image!='png'){
                                    if(image!='gif'){
                                        alert('Invalid Image Extension. Allowed extension is jpg,jpef,png,gif');
                                        $wk_jq(this).val('');
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    $wk_jq('.left').insertAfter('.buttons-set:last');


                    jQuery('#save_butn').click(function(e){
                        if(dataForm.validator.validate()!=false){   
                            var descrip = nicEditors.findEditor( "compdesi" ).getContent();
                            var regex = /<script(.+?)<\/script>/g;
                            var result = descrip.replace(regex,"");
                            result = result.replace(/script/g,'');
                            nicEditors.findEditor( "compdesi" ).setContent(result);
                            jQuery('#compdesi').text(result);

                            <?php
                            if(Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_options/partner_policy_approval')){?>
                                var returnpolicy = nicEditors.findEditor( "returnpolicy" ).getContent();
                                var shippingpolicy = nicEditors.findEditor( "shippingpolicy" ).getContent();
                                var regex = /<script(.+?)<\/script>/g;
                                var result1 = returnpolicy.replace(regex,"");
                                result1 = result1.replace(/script/g,'');
                                nicEditors.findEditor( "returnpolicy" ).setContent(result1);
                                jQuery('#returnpolicy').text(result1);

                                var result2 = shippingpolicy.replace(regex,"");
                                result2 = result2.replace(/script/g,'');
                                nicEditors.findEditor( "shippingpolicy" ).setContent(result2);
                                jQuery('#shippingpolicy').text(result2);
                            <?php
                            }?>

                            jQuery('#form-profile-validate').submit();
                        }
                    });


                    jQuery('#savepaym').click(function(e){
                       var pay = jQuery('#paymentsource').val();
                       var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
                        var result = descrip.replace(regex,"");
                        jQuery('#paymentsource').val(result); 
                    });

                    $wk_jq('.input-text').change(function(){
                        var validt = $wk_jq(this).val();
                        var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
                        var mainvald = validt .replace(regex, "");
                        $wk_jq(this).val(mainvald); 
                    });

                    $wk_jq('.profileimage_set span').click(function(event){
                        var dicisionapp=confirm('<?php echo $helper->__(" Are you sure you want to delete this banner ? ")?>');
                        if(dicisionapp==true){      
                            var thisthis = $wk_jq(this);
                            $wk_jq('.wk_banner').css('opacity','.7');           
                            $wk_jq.ajax({
                                url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/deleteprofileimage');?>",
                                type: "POST",
                                data: {file:'banner'},
                                dataType: 'html',
                                success:function(content){
                                    thisthis.parent('.setimage').remove();
                                }
                            });                         
                        }       
                    });

                    $wk_jq('.wk_profileimagedelete img').mouseover(function(event){
                        $wk_jq(event.target).css('width','22px');
                    });
                    $wk_jq('.wk_profileimagedelete img').mouseout(function(event){
                        $wk_jq(event.target).css('width','20px');
                    }); 

                    $wk_jq('.logoimage_set span').click(function(event){
                        var dicisionapp=confirm('<?php echo $helper->__(" Are you sure you want to delete this Logo ? ")?>');
                        if(dicisionapp==true){      
                            var thisthis = $wk_jq(this);
                            $wk_jq('.wk_logo').css('opacity','.7');         
                            $wk_jq.ajax({
                                url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/deletelogoimage');?>",
                                type: "POST",
                                data: {file:'logo'},
                                dataType: 'html',
                                success:function(content){
                                    thisthis.parent('.setimage').remove();
                                }
                            });                         
                        }       
                    });

                    $wk_jq('.wk_logoimagedelete img').mouseover(function(event){
                        $wk_jq(event.target).css('width','22px');
                    });
                    $wk_jq('.wk_logoimagedelete img').mouseout(function(event){
                        $wk_jq(event.target).css('width','20px');
                    });             
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    <?php 
    }else{
        echo "<h2 class='wk_new_msg'>".$helper->__("To BECOME SELLER PLEASE CONTACT TO ADMIN.")."</h2>";
    }?>


    <style>

    .div_link-cart { display:none !important  }
    .header_search { display:none !important; }
    .inner_menu    { display:none !important  }



    .header_top    { display:none !important  }
    .welcome-msg   { display:none !important  }
    .social-icons  {  display:none !important }

    .grid_6.pull_18.col-left.sidebar > div:last-child {
        display: none;
    }

    ul.wk_cont_ul li {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    </style>
```

Comment: first set the template 1column layout..

Comment: please inform what xml code i need to add in which file to set this as 1 column layout....

Comment: <marketplace_marketplaceaccount_editprofile>
  
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</marketplace_marketplaceaccount_editprofile>

Comment: i done this, than what i have to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add your menu here from xml

```
    <marketplace_marketplaceaccount_editprofile>
     <reference name="header"> 
    <block type="core/template" name="custom-top-links" template="test/link.phtml" after="-" />
     </reference> 
   </marketplace_marketplaceaccount_editprofile>
```

or use this for direct code add this in you file first line..

```
<?php echo  Mage::app()->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('core/template')
    ->setTemplate('test/link.phtml')
    ->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: i updated the code as you said, check the  updated question, but its not displaying menu.....

Comment: ->setTemplate('test/link.phtml')  add your menu file name

Comment: this is file path : app/design/frontend/default/em0113/template/marketplace/edit_myprofile.phtml

i used like this : ->setTemplate('test/edit_myprofile.phtml')   what else need to add?

Comment: ur side menu file path marketplace/filename or create new file for top

Comment: http://4.videomergerapp.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/editprofile/

http://4.videomergerapp.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/new/  compare 2 links ,some menus are missing

Comment: there is six menu item i can see

Comment: here there is 10 menu items : http://4.videomergerapp.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/new/   these 4 are missing : Assign Product
Assign Product List
Mass Upload Product
Manage Shipping above 4 are coming from extensions.... how to display these 4 also.....

Comment: on the template hint please

Comment: http://4.videomergerapp.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/editprofile/?tp=1&code=toy  you can use this suffix "?tp=1&code=toy  "

Comment: add these link also in you phtml menu file

Comment: now please check link : http://4.videomergerapp.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/editprofile/ other 4 menus are displaying as separate section, i updated the question , please check the code there......

Comment: make container of menu add div on them and add css from there

Comment: please check this : http://4.videomergerapp.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/editprofile/  i want to make "3 main menu" items and include these 10 menu items as sub menus [ example : http://videomergerapp.com/ ]

Comment: please help me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666388/create-new-menu-bar-and-add-sub-menus-in-magento-site